# neo4jclient Why does executing this query work from the browser but not via the app

Tags: .net, neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

For some reason executing the query via the code gives error but if I type it directly in the terminal(browser) it goes through.
My code:

```
var accountGuids = match.PlayerIDsScores.Keys.ToArray();
var gameScores = match.PlayerIDsScores.Values.ToArray();
    var query = _neo.Cypher
        .Match("(q:Quiz)")
        .Where((Quiz q) => q.ID == match.QuizID)
        .Merge("(m:Match $prop)-[u:USED]->(q)")
        .WithParams( new { prop = matchPoco})
        .With("m, $propac AS accounts, $propscore AS scores")
        .WithParams( new { propac = accountGuids, propscore = gameScores})
        .Unwind("range(0,size(accounts)-1)", "index")
        .OptionalMatch("(a:Account)")
        .Where("a.ID = accounts[index]")
        .Merge("(a)-[p:PARTICIPATED_IN]->(m)")
        .Set("p.GameScore = scores[index]");
    Console.WriteLine(query.Query.DebugQueryText);
    await query.ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

The string I got with Console.WriteLine:

```
MATCH (q:Quiz)
WHERE (q.ID = "fafbcc2f-fd67-42c9-bd65-7609142e041e")
MERGE (m:Match {
  ID: "3fa95f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
  Created: "\"2023-01-07T09:37:10.197Z\"",
  InviteCode: "string",
  GameState: "Waiting",
  HostID: "c098d8d4-a913-49c8-9a5e-18c5d60967a9",
  WinnerID: "c098d8d4-a913-49c8-9a5e-18c5d60967a9",
  Guests: "{\"additionalProp1\":15,\"additionalProp2\":0,\"additionalProp3\":0}"
})-[u:USED]->(q)
WITH m, [
  "c098d8d4-a913-49c8-9a5e-18c5d60967a9",
  "d4771807-4bea-406f-a1d9-8b690bb49c1b",
  "debe6b96-f151-4080-a4b4-d27f56bac0f3"
] AS accounts, [
  100,
  75,
  50
] AS scores
UNWIND range(0,size(accounts)-1) AS index
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:Account)
WHERE a.ID = accounts[index]
MERGE (a)-[p:PARTICIPATED_IN]->(m)
SET p.GameScore = scores[index]
```

And the error message is:

```
at Neo4jClient.GraphClient.Neo4jClient.IRawGraphClient.ExecuteCypherAsync(CypherQuery query)
   at MatchService.SaveMatchQueryAsync(Match match)
   at MatchService.SaveMatchAsync(Match match)
   at MatchController.SaveMatch(Match match)
   at lambda_method68(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker 
invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) 
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable 
scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable 
scope)
```

If I copy/paste the string that I got from Console.WriteLine(query.Query.DebugQueryText) into the browser terminal it executes without any problems, but when I try to do it with .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync() it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

Aight found the fix, turns out for some reason I can't do this:

```
.Merge("(m:Match $prop)-[u:USED]->(q)")
    .WithParams( new { prop = matchPoco})
```

I had to do it manually...

```
.Merge("(m:Match { ID: $mID, Created: $mCreated, InviteCode: $mInviteCode, GameState: $mGameState, HostID: $mHostID , WinnerID: $mWinnerID, Guests: $mGuests})-[u:USED]->(q)")
        .WithParams( new { 
            mID = matchPoco.ID,
            mCreated = matchPoco.Created,
            mInviteCode = matchPoco.InviteCode,
            mGameState = matchPoco.GameState,
            mHostID = matchPoco.HostID,
            mWinnerID = matchPoco.WinnerID,
            mGuests = matchPoco.Guests 
            })
```